# How to push config changes using spring-cloud-bus for local resource served via native profile?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

As mentioned [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-bus/reference/html/) and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-bus/), spring-cloud-bus can be used to push config changes to the client nodes based on the event received from a Git webhook.

I am trying to achieve a similar behavior but for configs served from the local disk (instead of a git repo) via spring-cloud-config's **native** profile mechanism.

Does spring-cloud-config provide any in-built components to monitor a local disk to identify config changes? or the only option is to write a custom config monitoring task to identify any changes - that will eventually trigger the `/actuator/busrefresh` endpoint.